# How to map single entity with two different node in @ResponseBody in springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson

I am using springboot app and I want to return json in the response obtained from converting  User object into json. I want to avoid creating two separate address class (billing and shipping) having specialized annotation on it. What should be the easy way for deserialization so that I could achieve my desire result.

Controller.java :

```
@RestController
public class Controller {
    @GetMapping("/user")
    public @ResponseBody User user() {
      User response = new User();
      response.setBillingAddress(new Address("line1", "newyork", "usa", "213321"));
      response.setShippingAddress(new Address("line2", "toronto", "canada", "342222"));
      return response;
    }
 }
```

User.java :

```
public class User {
    private Address billingAddress;
    private Address shippingAddress;
}
```

Address.java :

```
public class Address {
    private String addressLne1;
    private String city;
    private String country;
    private String postalCode;
}
```

Expected Json Response:

```
{
  "data": {
    "billing_information": {
      "billing_address_line1": "line1",
      "billing_city": "newyork",
      "billing_country": "usa",
      "billing_postal_code": "213321",
    },
    "shipping_information": {
      "shipping_address_line1": "line2",
      "shipping_city": "toronto",
      "shipping_country": "canada",
      "shipping_postal_code": "342222"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd have introduced two child classes of `Address`. They are different, by your definition, and having them as a one class is not the best design.

Comment: May I ask why do you want to prefix properties with `billing_` prefix in `billing_information`? It is already known that `city` or `country` are related to `billing` not `shipping`. Double context in property names looks like overkill.

Comment: It is require  in my case . I am developing a kind of proxy web service and the response my service return should be same as what I received from backend. Here I just want to define a logic to append prefix.